# How do I convert coefficient values from 1/3 octave band to 1/1 octave band?

Tags: acoustics

I have some coefficient values i.e. `74.9`, `81.3`, and `80.5` at frequency centers `63`, `160` and `400` Hz. The values are `1/3` octave band values. I would like to convert them to the `1/1` octave band values. Can someone suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to sum up levels given as 1/3 octave bands into 1/1 octave band resolution. This can be accomplished by decibel summation:

$L_\Sigma = 10 * log(10^\frac{L1}{10} + 10^\frac{L2}{10} + 10^\frac{L3}{10})$

Where $L$ are levels in dB.

Please see [here](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-octave.htm) for an online summation tool.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is,  you cannot calculate octave-band levels from single 1/3-octave band levels only.  For example, in order to calculate the 63-Hz octave band level,  you must know the the 50, 63 and 80-Hz 1/3-octave levels,  and add them according to the formula for decibel summation as above.